# pax-jdbc PostgreSQL JBoss Fuse

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jboss, jbossfuse

Exploring to use pax-jdbc for managing database connection pooling for the integrations. I followed the steps in this tutorial from Christian Schneider.

http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access

However came across following issues,

1) If I restart the containe, pax-jdbc does not creates the connection pool, until i update the config files in etc directory. Not sure if I have missed any configuration.

2) I also did not find any documentation on to use enrypted password in config files with pax-jdbc. I have setup the decryption password and environment variables (JASYPT_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD) and would like jasypt plugin to use it. Not sure how to request pax-jdbc to use it.

Appreciate if anyone can help me resolve above issues.

I am currently using,
- pax-jdbc - 0.6.0 version
- JBoss Fuse ESB - 6.2
- Database - PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: Just found out that there is bug in Jboss Fuse 6.2 version. Sharing the link with others for your information. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-4428

Answer (score 0):

I created a jasypt osgi service and the snapshot version of pax-jdbc 0.8.0 was able to find it and decrypt the passwords from the properties file. This did not worked with pax-jdbc 0.6.0 version. I did not try with 0.7.0 versio. However will try  it and update this post.

Can anyone let me know the timelines/date for pax-jdbc 0.8.0 version release?